# I can't compare moment dates even when using isSame. What is the problem?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, momentjs

I have a set of computed properties. One showing current date and one that shows a date from a database column. I need to compare these two dates.

I have tried using "isSame" as mentioned in the moment.js documentation, but the console returns "dates match" even if they don't match.

Can someone tell me what I missed? I looked in vue devtools and the dates display in the same format, so that shouldn't be the problem.

```
computed: {
  getCurrentDate() {
    return moment().locale(this.$i18n.locale).format('L')
  },
  deadline() {
    return moment(this.reservation.deadline).locale(this.$i18n.locale).format('L');
  },
  compareDates() {
    if (moment(this.deadline).isSame(this.getCurrentDate)) {
      console.log('dates match')
    } else {
      console.log('dates do not match')
    }
  },
}
```

Comment: can you provide input examples? Is this a new project (if so don't use moment, its basically [sunsetted](https://momentjs.com/docs/))?

Comment: the [docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-same/) also mention `moment().isSame() has undefined behavior and should not be used`

Comment: docs-content mentioned by @depperm:  _NOTE: moment().isSame() has undefined behavior and should not be used! If the code runs fast the initial created moment would be the same as the one created in isSame to perform the check, so the result would be true. But if the code runs slower it's possible that the moment created in isSame is measurably after the one created in moment(), so the call would return false._

Comment: @depperm, you misunderstood the warning. It basically says `isSame()` should not be used without an argument (or with an expression evaluating as falsy). Using it with a valid date is perfectly safe.

Comment: @A-Tech, the above comment is also addressed to you, but a comment can't mention more than one user.